# Rest API call with api_key in header fails if nginx is proxying moqui application

Tags: moqui

When run moqui on 8080 port, and access it directly by api

```
curl -X GET -H "api_key: {apiKey}" http://localhost:8080/rest/s1/example/examples/TEST2
```

it returns json result of example TEST2.

But when nginx is put in front of mqoui application. proxy to http://localhost:8080, then the api access fails with 403

```
{
  "errorCode": 403,
  "errors": "User null is not authorized for View on REST Path /example/examples/{exampleId}\nCurrent artifact info: [name:'/example/examples/{exampleId}', type:'AT_REST_PATH', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: true, granted:false, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]\nCurrent artifact stack:\n[name:'/example/examples', type:'AT_REST_PATH', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: false, granted:null, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]\n[name:'/example', type:'AT_REST_PATH', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: false, granted:null, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]\n[name:'component://webroot/screen/webroot/rest.xml/s1', type:'AT_XML_SCREEN_TRANS', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: false, granted:null, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]\n[name:'component://webroot/screen/webroot/rest.xml', type:'AT_XML_SCREEN', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: false, granted:null, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]\n[name:'component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml', type:'AT_XML_SCREEN', action:'AUTHZA_VIEW', required: false, granted:null, user:'null', authz:'null', authAction:'null', inheritable:false, runningTime:0]"
}
```

It appears webFacade does not initialize userFacade by api_key successfully, since in errors user is null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nginx disallows underscore _ in the header name by default. Moqui api use api_key or login_key that contains underscore, so the api_key or login_key header is not passed to backend moqui application.

Enable underscore in header name in nginx is simple, add

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

in http or server directive in nginx configuration.

Comment: On a side note, we could look for headers other than api_key and login_key, the 'api_key' name comes from looking at a few commonly used Swagger APIs and is supported in Swagger UI but there is nothing else special about it.